# Lost connection to MySQL server in aws lambda python

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda, mysql-connector-python

Hello I am trying to execute mysql query on aws lambda with python.
whenever i try to setup database connection inside the lambda function it works fine but when I try to setup database connection outside the lambda function it works only one time after it throwing Lost connection error. I think its not good practice to setup database connection each and every time inside the function.
Is there any other way? Answer will be really appreciated Thank you,

```
import mysql.connector

dataBase = mysql.connector.connect(
        host ="host endpoint",
        user ="user",
        passwd ="password",
        database = "db_name"
        )
cursorObject = dataBase.cursor()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        query = f"select * query"
        cursorObject.execute(query)
        ...
        ...
        return
```

Comment: I'm facing this kind of issue while connecting to MySQL server in AWS lambda using python.
Someone's help is really appreciated.

Comment: I just switched to posgress and it working fine even after setup connection outside the handler or you can keep connection code inside handler function